# Where to save and load large files in IOS

Tags: ios, swift

I want to in my app, be able to allow users to save large images(jpg) as well as data for each image(txt) and load the images/data.  I'm having trouble figuring out where to save these images and text files.  Userdefault wouldnt work because of the size of the image files and I don't want to save in the documents directory because then the user can access and potentially corrupt the data.

Where is a good place to save large data files for my app so I can load them later?

Comment: Use core data for store image.

Comment: I don't want user to access the saved data so I can just not put "Application supports iTunes file sharing" in my info.plist?

Comment: @bakalolo did you finally solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can save and retrieve your files in application **directory** folder. Also you can use **iCloud** to save your files.

Use below code if you want to save and retrieve files from Directory folder .

**Xcode 8.3.2 Swift 3.x**. Using NSKeyedArchiver and NSKeyedUnarchiver

**Reading file from documents**

```
let documentsDirectoryPathString = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
let documentsDirectoryPath = NSURL(string: documentsDirectoryPathString)!
let jsonFilePath = documentsDirectoryPath.appendingPathComponent("Filename.json")

let fileManager = FileManager.default
var isDirectory: ObjCBool = false

if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: (jsonFilePath?.absoluteString)!, isDirectory: &isDirectory) {

let finalDataDict = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: (jsonFilePath?.absoluteString)!) as! [String: Any]
}
else{
     print("File does not exists")
}
```

**Write file to documents**

```
NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(finalDataDict, toFile:(jsonFilePath?.absoluteString)!)
```

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you don't want to use the documents directory, or you want those data in a separate folder, or you don't want to permanently save them, you can also create your own temporary directory

saving data as file in a new directory **(swift 3)**:

```
func saveToMyDirectory(data: Data, filename: String) {
    var tempDirectoryURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: NSTemporaryDirectory(), isDirectory: true)
    tempDirectoryURL = tempDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(filename)
    do {
        try data?.write(to: tempDirectoryURL)
    } catch {}
}
```

Alternative approach: use Apple's UIDocumentInteractionController or UIActivityViewController and let the user choose how to save his/her documents:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentinteractioncontroller

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityviewcontroller